# Is unsetting environment variables always cause some fallback behavior?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Regarding Bourne shell and derivates, I understand `IFS` to be a behavior program for field splitting (commanding how to split fields into "words") which is needed for a broader process named "parsing".

I have read that If `IFS` (as an environment variable) is not set (as with `unset IFS`), the shell **shall behave as if** the value of IFS is `<space>`, `<tab>` and `<newline>`.

---

Putting the possible atrocious consequences aside for a moment, intuitively I would think that unsetting an environment variable would delete it without warnings similar to how `rm -rf /*` can just destroy a system without warnings and similar to what happens with `unset xyz` (as unsetting an artificially made non environment variable which is then deleted).

---

So, I would say that `unset IFS` isn't really unsetting it but resetting it (somewhere else) into some default fallback behavior.

Is unsetting environment variables always cause some fallback behavior?

Comment: I can't help but wonder where this question is coming from. Note that the [POSIX text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639727/170373) or e.g. Bash's manual don't say that `IFS` would be set to `<space><tab><newline>`if unset, just the relevant functions (i.e. field/word splitting and `$*`) act like it would have that value. Also, `IFS` is a somewhat special case in being integral to how the shell works. Is there some reason in particular to assume that unset variable in general wouldn't be basically deleted?

Comment: `just the relevant functions (i.e. field/word splitting and $*) act like it would have that value` isn't that the main functionality of IFS?

Comment: `Is there some reason in particular to assume that unset variable in general wouldn't be basically deleted?` Because I understood, most probably wrongly, that `unset IFS` would reset its value to `<space><tab><newline>` and I wanted to understand why.

Comment: @ilkkachu this question comes from me confusing `If IFS is not set, the shell shall behave as if the value of IFS is <space>, <tab> and <newline>` (especially the `will behave as`) with `will reset as` or `will fallback to`. Still this `will behave as` resembles some fallback behavior... Wouldn't you say?...

Comment: Anyway, @ilkkachu I have edited to improve the question based on your helpful comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not `bash` specific, but applies to all shells that implement POSIX behavior.

Unsetting `IFS` with `unset IFS` will unset the variable. It will not magically get another value.

The POSIX standard explicitly says

> If `IFS` is not set, it shall behave as normal for an unset variable [...]

It goes on to say that when the shell wants to do field splitting (splitting unquoted values, splitting `read` input, but also when delimiting the positional parameters in the `"$*"` string), and when `IFS` is unset, it should behave *as if* the `IFS` variable had the value of a space, tab and newline character.

This is not different than saying that a utility (in this case, the shell) will use a variable if it's available, and otherwise have some well defined default behavior.

Also note that `IFS` is not, and should not be, an environment variable.  I.e., it never needs to be exported.  It's only ever used by the current shell and its built in `read` utility.  A shell will set `IFS` to a space, tab and newline character when it starts.

See also the section on special [shell variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) in the POSIX standard.

Comment: I always enjoy when I read your answers.

Comment: About *unset or null*; I think that this "null" is different than the null of `IFS=`, `IFS=''` and `IFS=""` were no field splitting will be performed at all and with `echo "$*"` all fields will be concatenated together with no spaces.

Comment: @variableexpander Sorry, the "or null" bit was something that I had no support for. It has been removed.